# Displaying adjacent boxed text (Zero-length/invisible delimiters for text properties?)

Tags: faces, text-properties

I'm interested in displaying adjacent boxed text using the `:box t` face property in the following manner for adjacent text:

[image: visibly delimited adjacent boxes]

**Is there an accepted convention for delimiting/isolating text properties between otherwise uninterrupted text?**

For review (from [Face Attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html)):

> :box
>
> Whether or not a box should be drawn around characters, its
>   color, the width of the box lines, and 3D appearance.

Since face and text properties are attached to characters this particular face property is sort of an odd member among text/face properties.  Almost all other properties I can think of would not be expected to make a visual distinction that a text property was "interrupted" between adjacent visible characters.  Whereas with `:box` you may wish to have a box boundary between respective "boxes".  I can also imagine wanting to "reset" a stipple pattern (thereby potentially interrupting the tiling pattern).  If you can think of any other circumstances please comment.

The only approach that came to mind other than using a null character (which doesn't work) was to include an arbitrary string and mark it invisible:

```
(insert
 (concat
  (propertize "foo"
              'font-lock-ignore t
              'face '(:box t))
  (propertize "X"
              'invisible t)
  (propertize "bar"
              'font-lock-ignore t
              'face '(:box t))))
```

Incidentally I suspect that I found a rendering bug in emacs while considering this.  The following code renders as follows, but transitions to the desired rendering when the cursor moves to adjacent to the invisible character.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear whether or not you should draw one or two boxes. (Ideally, another solution should be implemented, say a :box-start property, so you would not have to resort to hacks like invisible text.) I can reproduce the rendering bug with Emacs 25.1 under Windows. Please report it as a bug to the Emacs team.

Comment: I have thought before that there should a character which is a "zero-width space"; considered as a space for word breaks etc, but be basically invisible. I'm surprised it does not yet exist. I suppose it should be a Unicode character, but you might also accomplish it with some Emacs magic.